# html variable doesnt contain something and if not, add it

Tags: php

Is it possible to see if the variable

`$url = $_POST["url"];`

doesnt contain "http://" or "https://" and if not add it on its beggining?
I have tried

```
if(strpos($url, "http://") == false || strpos($url, "https://") == false)
        {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
        }
```

and then

```
echo $url;
```

but when I run it it doesn't do anything. :(

My server is running on PHP 5 if that helps.
EDIT: I saw that the error was coming from another piece of code and i fixed it :P sorry for the inconvinience

Answer (score 0):

What about using substring instead?
And checking if the substring starting from 0 contains what you want?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't do anything? I suspect it would prepend `http://` to any `url` parameter.

You'll want `=== false` (triple `=`), because `== false` is the same as `== 0`,
which is true for any URL starting with `http://` or `https://`.

For more information see the warning message at [PHP strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
function isContainWith($content, $filter) {
    //preg_match("/$filter/", $content)
    return (strpos($content, $filter) > 0);
}

$url = $_POST["url"];
if (isContainWith($url, "http://") || isContainWith($url, "https://")) {
   $url = "http://" . $url;
}
```